# css sub-menu vanishes before I can click, need help to identify bug(s)

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have a horizontal menu coded in html and css only, this menu has sub-menu and some sub-menu has sub-menu of their own.

It works fine with the first level sub-menu only, but when I insert some sub-menu for any individual sub-menu, they still show up. But I can not reach to click them, they vanishes as my cursor moves. A demo can be found here : http://example.bojroninad.net/pages/menu_demo1.html

However, I was able to watch some steady behavior of this menu sometimes, but most of the time they vanishes before I reach to them.
 Here is my html code(pardon me for bad structured code):

```
`<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="menu1_css.css" media="screen" type="text/css">

<div id="menu1">


<ul> 
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">About</a> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="#">History</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Team</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Offices</a></li> 
</ul> 
</li> 
<li><a href="#">Services</a> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="#">Web Design        </a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Internet Marketing</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Hosting           </a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Domain Names      </a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">.ORG</a></li>
<li><a href="#">.COM</a></li>
<li><a href="#">.NET</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Broadband         </a></li> 
</ul> 
</li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="#">United Kingdom</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">France        </a></li> 
<li><a href="#">USA    &nbsp; </a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Australia     </a></li> 
</ul> 
</li> 
</ul>
</div>
</html>`
```

and  my css code goes here:

```
#menu1 {
background-color:#ccc;
width:100%;
height:30px;
}

#menu1 ul{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}


#menu1 ul li
{
list-style:none;
display:inline;
margin-left:10px;
float:left;
height:30px;
position:relative;
} 

#menu1 ul li a{
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:Bitstream Cyberbit,Garamond, Minion Web, ITC Stone Serif, MS Georgia;
color:green;
}

#menu1 li a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}

#menu1 li ul {
display:none;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:20px;
width:120px;
background-color:#999;
}

#menu1 li:hover ul{
display:block;
width:160px;
}

#menu1 li li {
display:list-item;
list-style:none;
}

/* second level sub menu */

#menu1 li li ul {
padding:0px;
margin-left:150px;
background-color:white;
top:0px;
position:relative;
}



#menu1 li li li{
display:none;
list-style:none;
position:absolute;
width:120px;
background-color:red;

}

#menu1 li  li:hover li{
display:block;
width:100px;
position:relative;
margin-left:0px; 
float:left;
height:30px;
}

#menu1 ul li li li a{
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:Bitstream Cyberbit,Garamond, Minion Web, ITC Stone Serif, MS Georgia;
color:yellow;
}

#menu1 li li li a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your second and third level list elements are also floated left, making them smaller than the menu itself.

You can solve it by setting:

```
#menu1 li li {
  float: none;         /* line 50 */
}
#menu1 li li ul {
  position: absolute;  /* line 57, is now relative, to avoid growth of li li */
}
```

Comment: Yes, now the menu is working more in a  more solid way. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

- As far as I can see, the menu works fine - except that the second-level menu is positioned a bit too low
- Usability would also be much better if you changed background color on li:hover + cursor:pointer - so you can see which button in the menu is active (and the user gets a visual feedback when he hovers out).

Comment: I was just testing, but your second suggestion gave me a way to polish my menu and a more efficient user experience. I will implement that. Thanks a lot.